# Can't resolve '@progress/kendo-react-treeview'

Tags: reactjs

[./node_modules/@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns/dist/es/DropDownTree/DropDownTree.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@progress/kendo-react-treeview' in 'D:\my_React_apps\amazon-clone - mystore\node_modules@progress\kendo-react-dropdowns\dist\es\DropDownTree'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtKp2.png)

Answer (score 6):

Did you install `@progress/kendo-react-treeview` ? May be you need to run

```
 npm i @progress/kendo-react-treeview --save
```

Comment: glad it helped. Please mark this as an accepted answer, so it can help others.